# How to add default text to search bar?

Tags: javascript, html, search, searchbar

Here is my problem:

When the **searchbox** get focused it become like this

```
--------------------

--------------------
```

Upon leaving the **searchbox** a string will automatically add to the **searchbox**

```
--------------------
Search
--------------------
```

What I want is when the searchbox get focus there will be a default string *Search* that when the user upon writing something the whole string *Search* will be replace with the string the user put in:

Once the user has done searching and want to search again the **searchbox** contains the string from earlier, what I want is when the user click on the searchbox it will automatically erase the string that exist in the **searchbox** and set it to default string.

Here is the code I so far:

```
<div id="search">
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>" >

<input id="s"  type="text" name="s" onfocus="if(this.value=='search site')
    {this.value=''};" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='search site'};" 
    value="<?php echo wp_specialchars($s, 1); ?>" />

<input id="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="" />
</form>

    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
```

Comment: Perhaps the placeholder attribute might be what you are looking for ? <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="something"/>

Comment: The textual description does not match the apparent intent of the code, which *clears* the field on focus. Please specify exactly what you want: a) what the field should contain initially, b) what should happen when it is focused, c) what should happen on user input, d) what should happen when the field loses focus? (Maybe first consider whether this is a good idea at all. Search fields should have labels, not initial content unless it is a useful default value.)

Comment: I edited your question to remove some - what we call here - "noise". Your English is really not that bad.

Comment: And what if the user wants to refine the search word instead of erasing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the HTML5 spec, you can simply use the `placeholder` attribute, like this:

```
<input id="s" type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search..." />
```

This will function exactly how you've described.

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Comment: Careful - this is a HTML5 attribute, and as a result, will cause W3C validation errors if the DOCTYPE isn't set for HTML5.

Comment: Noted.  I've updated my answer to point this out.

Comment: No, the question says “What I want is when the searchbox get focus there will be a default string”. The `placeholder` attribute makes the string appear in the field initially.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - I read the question, and provided an answer for what I believe he was asking for.  Ok, the string appears initially also.  He didn't specifically state that it was required for the field to be blank before the user interacted with it.  It's blatantly obvious that he's looking for placeholder text, which is exactly what I've provided him with.

Comment: *If* the question really asks for a placeholder, contrary to what the question says, then it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: The OP states that his English isn't good, which could explain his lack of a clear question.  That doesn't mean you should down-vote potentially correct answers because you believe my interpretation of his question is incorrect.  My answer is valid, and works towards the problem he outlined.

Comment: question clearly says to clear box onfocus and placeholder can not do it.

Comment: Thanx mate this really helped. Though it didnt resolve all of my concerns at first but ofc it's my bad because of my bad question formating. with this and a littel more code that i figured out the problem is solved. thanx again for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are talking for this

```
<input id="s" type="text" name="s" />
<script>
function addEvents(id) {
    var field  = document.getElementById(id);
     field.onfocus  = function ()  {
        this.value  = "";
    };
     field.onblur  = function ()  {
        if (this.value  == "")  {
            this.value  = "Search";
        }
    };
}
addEvents("s");
</script>
```